# How to deserialize JSON response to a complex Java object with nested fields and a map using Jackson?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, integration-testing, spring-test

I have created an **OrderCount** class in Java which contains several fields including strings, integers, nested objects, and a map. Here's the structure:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderCount {
    private String entityId;
    private String entityName;
    private Integer totalTests;
    @Builder.Default
    private Map<String, Integer> products = new HashMap<>();
    private List<OrderCount> childEntities;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Integer> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProductProperty(String name, Integer value) {
        products.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

**entityId** should map to **entityId.**

**entityName** should map to **entityName.**

**totalTests** should map to **totalTests.**

**childEntities** should map to **childEntities.**

Remaining fields should map to the **products map (Map<String, Integer>)**.

I expect guidance on how to properly deserialize the JSON response into an **OrderCount** object using **Jackson**, ensuring that the fields are mapped correctly as described above. However, if some alternative approaches or libraries could achieve the same result effectively, I welcome suggestions and assistance in exploring those options to find the most suitable solution. Additionally, if this task can be accomplished using any mapper or converter provided by the MapStruct library, I would appreciate guidance on that as well, as I have utilized MapStruct in my project.

The response I'm getting :

```
{
    "entityId": "01",
    "entityName": "entityName",
    "totalTests": 06,
    "childEntities": [
        {
            "entityId": "01",
            "entityName": "entityName",
            "totalTests": 03,
            "productName1":01,
            "productName2":01,
            .
            .
            .
            "productName_n":01,
        },
        {
            "entityId": "02",
            "entityName": "entityName_2",
            "totalTests": 3,
            "productName1":01,
            "productName2":01,
            .
            .
            .
            "productName_n":01,
            "childEntities": []     
        }
    ],
    "productName1":02,
    "productName2":02,
    .
    .
    .
    "productName_n":02,
}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON response with the values you get?

Comment: @GauthamChurchill I edited the question and added the response which I'm getting , Thanks.

Comment: Custom Deserializer: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: First off: You have to be careful. This is not valid JSON. Numbers may not start with a zero in JSON, i.e. `06`. For the actual question, personally I'd just de-serialization into a tree model and write a relatively trivial loop/recursion function to create the objects.